# I would like add GPA in my code but unfortunately not working

Tags: netbeans-8

I would ask if someone can help me the GPA in my code not working as per required.please find below it.

Scanner Student=new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please Enter Three Marks for Student");

```
            int sum=0;

            double avg;
            int[]x=new int[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("The mark : "+ ( i +1));
        x[i]=Student.nextInt();
        sum=sum+x[i];
```

}

```
         char grade;

        if (sum >= 90 )
  {
     grade = 'A';
  }
  else if (sum >= 80 )
  {
     grade = 'B';
  }
  else if (sum >= 70)
  {
     grade = 'C';
  }
  else if (sum >= 50)
  {
     grade = 'D';
  }
  else
  {
     grade = 'F';
  }

  // Display the grade.
                    System.out.println("The grade is " + grade);

        avg=sum/x.length;
                    System.out.println("The total of three marks are :"+sum+"\nThe Average is :"+avg);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what the issue is with the code? Do you get error messages or does it run and the result is just wrong?

Comment: the result is done but the GPA not working ex. if you see above the result >=80 should be the GPA is B but final result give me GPA is A very time .

Comment: Can you give an example of the wrong result you are getting with example inputs? This information should preferably be edited into your question

Comment: ex. while insert the marks for student. 80+80+80=240 the avg = 80% then the GPA is B but currently give me A not B

Comment: You are currently using the sum to determine the grade, not the average. Your sum is 240 which is >90, so grade='A'. You need to use the average in your if statements.

Comment: Example :Please Enter Three Marks for Student
The mark : 1
90
The mark : 2
80
The mark : 3
70
The grade is A
The total of three marks are :240
The Average is :80.0

Comment: while change avg instead of sum give me error :)

Comment: That's because you don't define the average isn't assigned a value until the end of your code. You need to compute the average before the if statements as well.

Comment: thank you very much  now is working perfect :)